# Checkbox inside button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to get a checkbox inside a button?

At the moment I have this solution:

```
<html>
<body>
   <div id="menu">
     <button><input type="checkbox" /></button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's ok, it works fine with Chrome and Firefox...but really awful with IE, so I need another way to achieve this goal.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I think its not a valid mark up to place a `checkbox` within a `button`. It would be better the button, replace with `span` and apply some CSS to `span` to make look like `button` and apply click event to that `span` and change the checkbox

Comment: Ok, i can try this, thanks :>

Comment: Or if you need to toggle the checkbox when button is clicked you can use `label` instead of `span` so you'll get the behaviour without javascript.

Comment: Ack, messing with checkboxes? A checkbox sets a boolean value, a button performs an action. Consider rethinking this; there's a reason that isn't valid markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here, so please forgive me if my answer isn't what you were looking for. If you want a button which changes the state of a checkbox, then @thecodeparadox's answer should work great, however if you're looking for a button which performs a function but also has a checkbox inside of it which can be toggled, you might want something like the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="button" href="#">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">Submit
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
#button {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.check {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

​**jQuery:**

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    window.location = '#';
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/278/

Comment: how is this the best answer? It's not valid html.

Answer (score 7):

I think its not a valid mark up to place a `checkbox` within a `button`. It would be better to replace the `button` with `span` or `div` and apply some `CSS` to `span` or `div` to make look like `button` and apply `click` event to that and change the `checkbox` state.

**[Just an example for you](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/246/)**

Comment: @Klemzy what is not working? Please explain or make a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net.. and place your code

Comment: Works with Chrome, Edge, not with IE, Firefox, so best to avoid, and use this suggested workaround

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

It's not valid markup but you can cheat IE with jquery -

```
<button>hi</button>
$('button').prepend('<input type="checkbox" />');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gg9fG/