# Access checkbox value inside button

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

So i have a screen that has a button and when clicking the button i can access a set of checkbox that I select the values. This checkbox list are a child component.

this checkbox list are in a component that has this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.toggleState = this.offerings.map(() => false)
    this.offerings.forEach((offering: ICategoryDto) => {
      offering.value.forEach((offeringValue: string) => {
        this.offeringState[offeringValue] = false
      })
    })
  }
```

Now i want to pass those checkbox value to the component that can save that do the service.
like this

```
  @Input() offerings: ICategoryDto[]
```

But this offerings only have all the values of the button and not the values of the checkbox inside it.
How can i pass those checkbox values to this father component ?
anyone ever did something similar?

Comment: HTML doesn't allow checkboxes to appear inside buttons.

Comment: show HTML of your child component.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible you can check in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11048134/4420482

Remember this is not valid mark up and some browser would not support this !
You should find a different solution for that problem.

I Believe that the reason is that both of them checkbox and button have click event bounded to them and some propagation issues might occur.